# Can we remove White spaces of Images in css?

Tags: jquery, css, photoshop

I want to remove white-space of images. How can I remove whites spaces of images using CSS or any other programming tools.

**Example Image:**
[image: Example]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you mean whitespace (i.e., the space that appears on screen between the borders of elements on a page) or do you mean that you want to effect something like an image crop, e.g., you have an image with a white border around the edges that you'd like to trim?

Answer (score 1):

You should export an transparent png.
There are an mask option -> https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ but very bad browser support. also i guess you won't sit 3 days on clipping the image lol

Answer (score -1):

It is available in photoshop.Open the file with Photoshop, remove white color by using magic tool and save as it with png file.